# Link is not clickable on first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with search feature on my web page.

The page contains auto focused text input element. When user is typing, the ajax request is performed then JQuery populates the div with search results. Each search result is an `<li>` element with link inside.

Here is how it looks:

[image]

What I want to achieve is click on link in search result (e.g. "iPhone SE") opens the new web page.

It works now in 2 clicks - first click on link loses the focus from text input and the second one opens the new page.

Any ideas how to open link in one click, without losing the input text focus first?

**The code**

Html layout for search:

```
            <!-- search form -->
            <div class="search-form d-none d-lg-inline-block">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <button type="button" name="search" id="search-btn" class="btn btn-flat">
                        <i class="mdi mdi-magnify"></i>
                    </button>
                    <input type="text" name="query" id="search-text" class="form-control" placeholder="Product name, Product code or Trade Document number" autofocus autocomplete="off" />
                </div>
                <div id="search-results-container">
                    <ul id="search-results-list"></ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript code of the page:

```
$(function () {
    // ...
    addSearchHandler()
    // ...
});
```

`addSearchHandler` is defined in another file search.js:

```
function addSearchHandler() {
    $("#search-text").on('change keyup copy paste cut', function() {
        var text = $('#search-text').val()
        if (text.length == 0 || text == '') {
            $('#search-results-list').html('')
            return
        }
        search(text)
    });
}

function search(term) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/search?term=' + term,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            searchResults(data)
        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.log('search error')
        }
    })
}

function searchResults(data) {
    var html = ''

    if (data.length == 0) {
        $('#search-results-list').html('<li>No Result Found</li>')
        return
    }

    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var type = capitalizeFirstLetter(data[i].type)
        var url = '#'
        var code = ''

        if (data[i].type == 'PRODUCT') {
            url = getProductURL(data[i])
            if (data[i].productSerialNumber != null && data[i].productSerialNumber.length > 0) {
                code = ' &bull; ' + data[i].productSerialNumber
            }

            html += '<li><div class="link"><a href="' + url + '">' + data[i].name + '</a></div><div class="location">' + type + code + '</div></li>'
        } else {
            url = getTradeDocumentURL(data[i])
            code = ' &bull; ' + data[i].documentId
            var title = getTradeDocumentTitle(data[i].documentId, data[i].tradeType)

            html += '<li><div class="link"><a href="' + url + '">' + title + '</a></div><div class="location">' + 'Trade' + code + '</div></li>'
        }
    }

    $('#search-results-list').html(html)
}

function getProductURL(item) {
    if (item.productId != null) {
        return '/html/product/details.html?id=' + item.productId
    } else {
        return '#'
    }
}

function getTradeDocumentURL(item) {
    if (item.documentId != null) {
        if (item.tradeType == 'ADD') {
            return '/html/trade/view_add.html?id=' + item.documentId
        }
        if (item.tradeType == 'SELL') {
            return '/html/trade/view_sell.html?id=' + item.documentId
        }
        if (item.tradeType == 'BUY') {
            return '/html/trade/view_buy.html?id=' + item.documentId
        }
        if (item.tradeType == 'WRITE_OFF') {
            return '/html/trade/view_write_off.html?id=' + item.documentId
        }
        if (item.tradeType == 'REFUND') {
            return '/html/trade/view_refund.html?id=' + item.documentId
        }
        if (item.tradeType == 'MOVE_IN' || item.tradeType == 'MOVE_OUT') {
            return '/html/trade/view_move.html?id=' + item.documentId
        }
        return '#'
    } else {
        return '#'
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: We need to see your code.

Comment: Thanks for comment, going to add the code now..

Comment: Updated the post with code.

Answer (score 0):

The search input handler was wrong 'change keyup copy paste cut'. Removing the 'change' event done the trick